# $("#list").setPostDataItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have used `setPostDataItem` for many times and it always works.  But recently I add some new code into my work, then firebug tells that `$("#list").setPostDataItem` is not a function.
I can't find why this happened, does anybody met this?

Answer (score 1):

The Post Data Module (which provides `setPostDataItem`) has been removed from jqGrid as of version 4.0.0 apparently. It needs to be included as a plugin. The instructions to do that are here: http://goo.gl/PhFSh

I would guess that jqGrid in your site was updated, that's why `setPostDataItem` is no longer there. If, on the other hand, you were already using a version above 4.0.0, then check that the plugin is being loaded correctly.

Comment: yes,you are right.I update jqgird to 4.3 version.Thanks very much.

Comment: @xiao.Ao: The answer of **MartinodF** is absolutely correct. You should just use `setGridParam` method instead of `setPostDataItem`. I want only to add that you can still find `setPostDataItem` in `grid.postext.js` of the `plugins` subdirectory of [jqGrid download](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). The better is do to use `setGridParam` method now.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some javascript function in the new functionality is breaking, which trickles down and is killing the `setPostDataItem` plugin...